# How to reliably get a destructor to overwrite buffer without it being optimized out in c++

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, clang, destructor

I'm reviewing someone else's code and I See the in a destructor he is overwriting a buffer that is an int array inside the class. I thought maybe the compiler might optimize that out.

So I made a small program to test, and it does optimize the destructor out.

The only simple solution to this I found is to use **attribute**((optimize("O0"))) on the destructor. But there has to be a way to do this without using gcc-specific attributes.

Things I tried:

1. Setting the buffer to be volatile -- this works if you directly set the buffer in a for loop (not a memset or the like). But I really don't want this to be volatile, since it's not.
2. **attribute**((optimize("O0"))) works but is not portable, and is kinda ugly.
3. making my own new/delete with it's own memory pool. I was thinking if the compiler doesn't know how the memory is being used, it shouldn't optimize writes to it. The fact that this didn't work seems like a bug.
4. Setting up a class whose only job is to overwrite the buffer in the other memory. This works but man is it needlessly ugly.

I'm thinking a lot of application would want to do something like this. Not just zeroing out keys. Surely someone has run into this issue before, or I'm just doing something wrong.

Ideas?

g++ memset.cpp -O1 -fsanitize=undefined -Wall -Wextra

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
class example{
public:
  int key[100];
  
  ~example(){
    printf("destructor\n");
    memset(key,0, sizeof(key));
  }
};

void print_memory(int *in){
  printf ("\n");
  for(int i =0; i < 10; i++){
    printf(" %2d:a: %08x ",i, in[i]);
  }
}

int main(){
  example *ptr;
  {
    example *it = new example;
    ptr = it;
    // fill memory with something.
    for(int i = 0; i< 100; i++){
      it->key[i] = rand();
    }
    
    printf("Done randomizing.\n");
    print_memory(it->key);
    delete it;
  }
  printf("\ndeleted\n");
  print_memory(ptr->key);
  printf("\n");
}
```

Output:
Done randomizing.

0:a: 6b8b4567   1:a: 327b23c6   2:a: 643c9869   3:a: 66334873   4:a: 74b0dc51   5:a: 19495cff   6:a: 2ae8944a   7:a: 625558ec   8:a: 238e1f29   9:a: 46e87ccd destructor

deleted

0:a: 00000000   1:a: 00000000   2:a: 0e57f010   3:a: 0000555b   4:a: 74b0dc51   5:a: 19495cff   6:a: 2ae8944a   7:a: 625558ec   8:a: 238e1f29   9:a: 46e87ccd

Comment: You never call the destructor of `example`. You have to explicitly call `delete it;` or create a `example` statically, using `example it;` instead of `example* it = new it;` Preferably the latter (statically create it) since using new/delete at all is a code smell.

Comment: As far as I know, people normally use OS functions like `SecureZeroMemory` and `explicit_bzero` for that, but I assume you're looking for something in the language and standard library itself.

Comment: John, your right. This was a broken version of my example. I'll update the comment with the delete.

Comment: Chris, this is bare metal. So, no OS.

Comment: If the class doesn't own the buffer it'll be harder for the compiler to decide that the code has no observable effect so might prevent the optimisation?

Comment: John, I fixed the code. It doesn't matter if it's on the stack or heap. Neither works.

Comment: Printing the array after the pointer has been deleted is UB. Doesn't that kind of make this example a bit useless?

Comment: The destructor appears to be memsetting ... the first 8 bytes of the array. `sizeof(int*)` shenanigans?

Comment: JohnFilleau, In some of these implementations (I've tried several things) the memory was being put in register space. That's why I had to up the buffer space to something bigish.

Comment: JohnFilleau, I added a printf("size of key: %ld\n", sizeof(key)); Just to be sure. And the size is 400 bytes. Although this printf made the example work. ;)

Comment: super, sorta. You certainly wouldn't want to do this in real code. This was just the simplest way to show the memory wasn't zeroed. This is important for keys to be zeroed, because anyone who might have gained access to your computer could write a simple program to search for keys in memory, even though they are no-longer used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bare metal way is to access it via volatile - that way it will not be optimized. A C way would be:

```
#include <cstddef>
void volatile_memset(volatile void *s, int c, size_t n) {
    volatile unsigned char *m = reinterpret_cast<volatile unsigned char *>(s);
    while (n--) {
       *m++ = c;
    }
}
int main() {
    char key[200];
    volatile_memset(key, 0, sizeof(key));
}
```

but I think in C++ you can:

```
#include <algorithm>
int main() {
    char key[200];
    std::fill_n<volatile char *>(key, sizeof(key)/sizeof(*key), 0);
}
```

or:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
int main() {
    char key[200];
    std::fill<volatile char *>(std::begin(key), std::end(key), 0);
}
```

Comment: Good idea! I like it.

Comment: I've tried both these, and they both work (as expected). This is the simplest solution I've seen.